# Custom font in WebView using CSS intermittently disappearing on Galaxy Tab

Tags: android, css, webview, font-face, galaxy

I got a problem [similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994118/android-custom-font-in-webview-using-css-issue)

In my case, I'm also using CSS to declare a font in a CSS file:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: MyriadPro;
    font-weight: bold;
    src: url('../resources/MyriadPro-Bold.otf');
}
```

Use it in a style:

```
.ueberschrift {
    font-family: MyriadPro, sans-serif;
    font-size: 2.4em;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 100% !important;
    margin: 0 0 0.4em 0;
}
```

Which displays just fine on a Samsung Smartphone, Acer- or Motorola Tablet. However, on the Samsumg Galaxy Tab, the font disappears a lot of the time. The space for the font is allocated, but nothing is rendered. To make matters worse, this bug does appear about 3 out of 4 times, but about 1 in 4 times the font DOES get rendered. Check the following screenshots:

[Font is rendered](http://www.webtecc.com/forum_images/font_rendered.png)

[Font is NOT rendered](http://www.webtecc.com/forum_images/font_not_rendered.png)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

try declaring the full path of the URL. i had an issue similar to this when i was using webink, but managed to resolve it when i used the full path.

Comment: When you say "full path of the URL" do you mean like: http:// example.com/resources/MyriadPro-Bold.otf or something starting from the root like: /fonts/resources/MyriadPro-Bold.otf

Comment: @Beau Hey there, I meant the former so it should read something like http://example.com/resources/MyriadPro-Bold.otf